# Mapbox GeoJSON in wrong position

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-android

Apologies in advance if this has been answered. I can not find anything online or in the repository pointing to my issue.

I have a `ArrayList<Position>` which is holding my line sting.

This display's fine when drawing it with `addPolyline`

I would like to style the line so I switched to using a line layer. However.

The line no long appears any where close to the correct location. The location is in Cumbria, England, but is drawn of the coast of Somalia.

I have tried to output the coordinates after each transformation and they all appear okay. I can not work out how to inspect the `source`

```
Log.d("Tracing 1", route.toString())

val lineString = LineString.fromCoordinates(route)

Log.d("Tracing 2", lineString.coordinates.toString())

val feature = Feature.fromGeometry(lineString)

Log.d("Tracing 3", feature.geometry.coordinates.toString())

val featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(
        arrayOf(feature))

val geoJsonSource: Source = GeoJsonSource("line-source", featureCollection)
mapboxMap.addSource(geoJsonSource)

val debugSource = mapboxMap.getSource("line-source") as GeoJsonSource
Log.d("Tracing 4", debugSource.toString())

val lineLayer = LineLayer("linelayer", "line-source")

lineLayer.setProperties(
        PropertyFactory.lineDasharray(arrayOf(0.01f, 2f)),
        PropertyFactory.lineCap(LINE_CAP_ROUND),
        PropertyFactory.lineJoin(LINE_JOIN_ROUND),
        PropertyFactory.lineWidth(5f),
        PropertyFactory.lineColor(Color.parseColor("#e55e5e"))
)

mapboxMap.addLayer(lineLayer)

val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(LatLng(route[0].latitude, route[0].longitude))
        .build()

mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
```

The log cat output showing that the `Log`s are all the same is here.

```
10-05 20:52:37.162 11449-11449/com.xxx.xxx D/Tracing 1: [Position [longitude=54.82269833333333, latitude=-2.8017883333333335, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82289833333333, latitude=-2.80173, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.823098333333334, latitude=-2.8015583333333334, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.8233, latitude=-2.8012799999999998, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82339833333334, latitude=-2.801078333333333, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82379833333333, latitude=-2.8007583333333335, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.8241, latitude=-2.8004183333333335, altitude=NaN]]

10-05 20:52:37.172 11449-11449/com.xxx.xxx D/Tracing 2: [Position [longitude=54.82269833333333, latitude=-2.8017883333333335, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82289833333333, latitude=-2.80173, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.823098333333334, latitude=-2.8015583333333334, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.8233, latitude=-2.8012799999999998, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82339833333334, latitude=-2.801078333333333, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82379833333333, latitude=-2.8007583333333335, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.8241, latitude=-2.8004183333333335, altitude=NaN]]

10-05 20:52:37.172 11449-11449/com.xxx.xxx D/Tracing 3: [Position [longitude=54.82269833333333, latitude=-2.8017883333333335, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82289833333333, latitude=-2.80173, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.823098333333334, latitude=-2.8015583333333334, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.8233, latitude=-2.8012799999999998, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82339833333334, latitude=-2.801078333333333, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.82379833333333, latitude=-2.8007583333333335, altitude=NaN], Position [longitude=54.8241, latitude=-2.8004183333333335, altitude=NaN]]

10-05 20:52:37.182 11449-11449/com.xxx.xxx D/Tracing 4: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource@9d382a28
```

The question I have is; am I doing something wrong is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For MapBox, you have to supply the latitude and longitude in reversed order.
Your problem is that you have switched up the longitude and latitude coordinates for each point.

Comment: Wow! That was quick and correct. Thank you. I was previously pulling them out of the database as LatLng and changed to Position for GeoJSON and never even saw the arguments differed. That had me stumped. Thanks again.

Comment: I was wondering would it be possible to do this on the fly somehow or am I stuck writing an update function to reverse all those one by one?